# Opentok video calling in safari using flash and webRTC

Tags: flash, webrtc, opentok

i am developing a application using flash and webRTC, 
it is working fine in webrtc 
but when it comes to safari, it is giving no error no warning nothing
how can i make it work

Comment: is your webRTC working with flash ? if yes then please share code how you enable flash in case of webrtc.

Answer (score 1):

Safari 11 will support WebRTC, expected release in 2017 fall. 
For more details, see release notes "Web conferencing. Implements peer to peer conferencing with the WebRTC standard." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Safari_11_0/Safari_11_0.html

Note that currently available with Safari Tech Preview or iOS beta versions.

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support webrtc natively, so webrtc will not work on safari. With that said, there are [plugins](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/) out there that can help browsers without webrtc become webrtc compatible.

Comment: can you tell me one, because i am not able to find it